# Turn off link on menu items without URLs

Tags: asp.net, menu, web-controls, aspmenu

I am building a menu for my asp.net application using the Menu control which is in turn being fed by a table via a Hierarchical data object.  It works great, except that I cannot figure out how to configure the Menu control to disallow clicking on the menu items with no designated URLs.

For instance, I have a static toplevel menu item.  I hover my mouse over it and a dynamic menu list appears for my choosing pleasure. Each dynamic menu item contains a link to a page that is invoked when I click my mouse on it. Whereas the static top level menu goes nowhere.  How can I  make it so that clicking on that top level static menu does not act like it is a link?

Thanks
jw

Answer (score 7):

Is this perhaps what you are looking for?:

```
<Items>
    <asp:MenuItem  Selectable="false" Text="Search Engines" >
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com" Text="Google"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com" Text="Google"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com" Text="Google"></asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem>
</Items>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yes.  That is exactly what I needed.  It really should have jumped out at me.  Thank you.